# Use bash to find first folder name that contains a string

Tags: bash, shell, find

I would like to do this in Bash:

- in the current directory, find the first folder that contains "foo" in the name

I've been playing around with the find command, but a little confused. Any suggestions?

Comment: A shame you want bash, zsh makes things like this much easier: `echo *(/[1])`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use the `-quit` option of `find`:

```
find <dir> -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*foo*' -print -quit
```

Comment: The `awk` command could be reduced to `awk NR==1`, but it'd be better to use `head -n1`.

Comment: Thanks! I also like the `head` attempt more. Don't know why awk was the first in my mind :) ...

Comment: how could we get last item instead of first?

Comment: on MacOS, I get illegal option m, (from -maxdepth option) =>   $ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*foo*'| head -n1
find: illegal option -- m
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: @AlexanderMills Thanks, you are right on MacOS/BSD the path argument is mandatory. You can omit it when using GNU find. The answer was old already, today I would recommend the `-quit` option.

Answer (score 14):

```
pattern="foo"
for _dir in *"${pattern}"*; do
    [ -d "${_dir}" ] && dir="${_dir}" && break
done
echo "${dir}"
```

This is better than the other shell solution provided because

- it will be faster for huge directories as the pattern is part of the glob and not checked inside the loop
- actually works as expected when there is no directory matching your pattern (then `${dir}` will be empty)
- it will work in any POSIX-compliant shell since it does not rely on the `=~` operator (if you need this depends on your pattern)
- it will work for directories containing newlines in their name (vs. `find`)

Comment: `$dir` will only be empty if your shell does not treat a non-matching glob as a literal string. If many files match the pattern, you may overflow the maximum allowed number of arguments.

Comment: @chepner I think you need to read my code again. The literal string would be set to $_dir, but not $dir since the test would evaluate to false.

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't noting the difference between `_dir` and `dir`. And I bet few directories have enough subdirectories (as opposed to files) to worry about generating too many arguments.

Comment: thanks for this, and to everybody else who contributed. Great discussion

Comment: Came back due to a random upvote and would like to add that this is *not* subject to `ARG_MAX` (@chepner). More info [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Heh :) I've never looked into the details, but I gather `ARG_MAX` is only relevant when building `argv` for an external command?

Comment: @chepner Yes, this only affects the underlying `exec()` (and related) syscall. Since `for` is a `bash` keyword this is not the case and `ARG_MAX` thus only affects externals (e.g. `/bin/echo`, but *not* `echo` if the shell provides it), not shell builtins or loops like this :)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth What is the meaning of th stars ? `*"${pattern}"*` ?

Comment: @Sandburg It's a wildcard, see [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Answer (score 10):

for example:

```
dir1=$(find . -name \*foo\* -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | head -n1)
echo "$dir1"
```

or (For the better shell solution see Adrian Frühwirth's answer)

```
for dir1 in *
do
    [[ -d "$dir1" && "$dir1" =~ foo ]] && break
    dir1=        #fix based on comment
done
echo "$dir1"
```

or

```
dir1=$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | grep 'foo' | head -n1)
echo "$dir1"
```

Edited head -n1 based on @ hek2mgl comment

Next based on @chepner's comments

```
dir1=$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | grep -m1 'foo')
```

or

```
dir1=$(find . -name \*foo\* -type d -maxdepth 1 -print -quit)
```

Comment: Both of these look awesome, thanks! But how can I store the full folder name in a variable?

Comment: If you have `foo` in a variable, try `... -name "*$variable*" ...` in the `find` command.

Comment: Your second solution will not work if there are folders in the directory, but none actually matches `foo`...then `$dir1` will be set to the last directory found.

Comment: If your `find` supports it, `-quit` *after* `-print` will cause `find` to exit after the first file is found. Similarly, `grep -m1 'foo'` will output only the first occurrence of 'foo' in its input.

Comment: In which case (-print -quit) it will also work with filenames with newlines and be possibly faster than the shell approach. This is *way* more elegant than using head or grep.

Comment: All these result in: `root@blustinkt:/home/teaspeak# dir1=$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | grep -m1 'Tea')
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
`

Comment: @Bluscream specific to the GNU-find. Also, it is just a warning. Move the `-maxdepth 1` before `-type d`. (e.g.it should be the first arg. after the `.`)