# Write a script that takes exactly one argument, a directory name

Tags: bash, sh

Write a script that takes exactly one argument, a directory name. The script should print that argument back to standard output. Make sure the script generates a usage message if needed and that it handles errors with a message.

I write code, how i understand. Am i understand correctly this question? Maybe there are other versions how find directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter fail name:"
read str

find "$str" 2>/dev/null

sa=$?

if [ "$sa" = '0' ]    
then    
   echo "$str"    
else
   echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: Use `[[ -d "$str" ]]` to check if argument is a directory, no need to use `find`

Comment: This may have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344365/use-bash-to-find-a-folder-name-that-contains-a-string .

Does this help you?

Comment: @alph486 I could not do with [[ -d "$str" ]]. How write in code?

Comment: Please see the attached link above to see if that solution works for you to find a directory using bash. Also, Is there a reason you have to write a script to do this? Can you just use a variation of the find command as shown in the link above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't appear to be using an argument. In `bash` the first one (`$0` is your script) would be `$1` and something like,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
  echo "$0: Please provide a directory name"
  exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
  echo "$0: $1 is not a directory name"
  exit 1
fi
echo "$1"
```

Comment: When I run this script, script print Please provide a directory name,and where i write directory name?

Comment: When you run the script (as a [command line argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments)). `./script <DIRECTORY>`

Comment: ou thanks worked, and what to write to check on files?

Comment: can you answer my this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/544186/create-a-script-that-takes-a-word-as-an-argument-from-the-user/544188#544188